# Difference between phrase and idiom

Tags: word-choice, phrases, idioms

What is the difference between a *phrase* and an *idiom*?

Comment: Have you looked up the words in the dictionary?

Answer (score 15):

A phrase is “a small group of words standing together as a conceptual unit”, while an idiom is “a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words”. So, the difference is that an idiom as an **established meaning not directly linked to the individual words**. Any idiom is a phrase.

As an example, “raining cats and dogs” is both an idiom and a phrase. “A herd of cats” is a phrase but not an idiom.

Comment: "A girl's best friend" definitely is an idiom if the speaker is using it to refer to diamonds.  :-)

Comment: @Hellion: yeah, I should have thought about diamonds. I've edited :)

Comment: So in other words, an idiom must have at least 2 words?

Comment: @Pacerier Probably not... like "bullshit" (originally)

Comment: Is bullshit an *idiom*? Isn't it just a *word*?

Comment: According to grammar, phrase has a different meaning.  An idiom can be a phrase, clause or a sentence.